# How can you display an specific number of rendering after mapping a json object?

Tags: loops, dictionary, reactjs, filtering

This is my json object.

"properties":{

```
        "summary":[
            {
                "id":0,
                "name": "John Doe",
                "address": "Privet Drive",
                "sex":"M"
            },
            {

                "id":1,
                "name": "John Smith",
                "address": "Elm Street",
                "sex":"M"
            },
            {

                "id":2,
                "name": "Jane Doe",
                "address": "Privet Drive B",
                "sex":"F"
            },
            {

                "id":3,
                "name": "Peter Parker",
                "address": "Privet Drive C",
                "sex":"M"
            },
            {

                "id":4,
                "name": "Harry Potter",
                "address": "Privet Drive D",
                "sex":"M"
            }
        ]

    }
```

This is the on my react file

```
class Thumbnail extends React.Component{
    render(){
    const datax = this.props.info;

        return (
            <div>
                {
                    datax.map(function(obj){
                        {
                            let summary = obj.properties.summary;
                            let summaryLength = summary.length;

                            return (
                                summary.map(function(item){

                                    return <div className={"col-md-3 col-sm-6"} key={item.id}>
                                            <p>
                                                <a href={'http://localhost:8080/'} className="listing-link">
                                                    <PersonName name={item.name} />
                                                </a>
                                            </p>
                                            <PersonAddress address={item.address} />
                                            <PersonSex address={item.sex} />
                                    </div>;

                                })
                            )
                        }
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The ReactDom.render is on a different file which I can access by this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Thumbnail info={data} />, document.getElementById('featured-list'));
```

I want to display only 4 sets of properties from the props object. This code displays 5 of them based on the props which has 5 sets.

I tried doing a iteration inside the map function but it fails.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: i think the json object is incomplete, where is info and summary?

Comment: You want to display first four sets (id's 0, 1, 2, 3)?

Comment: @Boky yes, I want to display the first four sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to display only first four sets. You can try like this :

```
summary.slice(0,4).map(function(item){ .... })
```

That will return only first four sets. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1435/)

*Another solution*

With the iteration inside the map function, you can do it like this :

```
{summary.map((s, i) => i <= 3 ? <div key={i}>{s.name}</div> : "")}
```

That will also return only first four sets. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1437/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: you sir are a genius! Thanks